# Program reprinting image after going through Mirror function

Tags: c, arrays, structure, ppm

I've been trying for days to figure out why my program is just reprinting the input image. I know my other functions work, but for some reason this one is stumping me I've tried every way I could think of to move pixels around, but absolutely nothing i have tried works.

header:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct pixel {
        char r, g, b;
};

int g_width, g_height;

void parseHeader( FILE *input );
void parseImage( FILE *input, struct pixel *theArray );
void print(struct pixel a[]);
void my_Mirror(struct pixel a[]);
void rotate(struct pixel a[]);
void my_Flip(struct pixel a[]);
```

main:

```
#include "transform.h"


int main (int argc, char *argv[])  {

        // declarations here
   FILE *inFile;


        // open input file 

   inFile = fopen(argv[2],"r");
   if (inFile == NULL)
   {         
      fprintf(stderr, "File open error. Exiting program\n");
      exit(1);
   }


        // parseHeader function call here
   parseHeader(inFile);       

        // malloc space for the array (example given in assignment write-up)
   struct pixel * image = 
          (struct pixel *) malloc(sizeof(struct pixel) * g_width * g_height);

        // parseImage function call here
   parseImage(inFile, image);

        // close input file 

   fclose(inFile);

        // manipulate the image according to command-line parameter
        //              1: mirror image
        //              2: upside down image
        //              3: rotate to the right 90 degrees

   if (atoi(argv[1]) == 1)
   {
      my_Mirror(image);
   }

   if (atoi(argv[1]) == 2)
   {
      my_Flip(image);
   }
   if (atoi(argv[1]) ==3)
   {
      rotate(image);
   }

   print(image);
   return 0;
}
```

mirror:

```
      void my_Mirror(struct pixel a[])
{
   int i,j,limit = 0;
   struct pixel temp;

   for(j = 0; j < g_height; ++j) //move through vertical pixels
   {
      for( i = 0; i < (g_width/2); i++)
      {
        temp = a[(j * g_width) + i];
        a[(j * g_width) + i] = a[((j+1)*g_width) - (1 + i)];
        a[((j+1)*g_width) - (1 + i)] = temp;
      }
   }
}
```

This is my horizontal flip function which works up until the mirror call if that helps:

```
#include "transform.h"

void my_Flip(struct pixel a[])
{
   struct pixel  temp;
   int i;
   int j = 0;

   for (i = (g_width * g_height); i >=  0; --i)
   {
      temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[(i-i)+j];  //swap values of pixels 
      a[(i-i)+j] = temp;

      ++j;

      if(j == (g_width * g_height)/2)
      {
         i = 0;
      }

   }
   my_Mirror(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pixel is not an intrinsic type, so must be copied via `memcpy`
    rather than as a simple assignment.

The code needs to validate the command line parameter
    and if the parameter does not contain a valid value
    then complain before exiting.

The code needs to validate the returned value from the input I/O
    functions to assure the operation was successful.

So here is a possible solution to your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pixel
{
        char r, g, b;
};

// global data
int g_width, g_height;

//prototypes
void parseHeader( FILE *input );
void parseImage( FILE *input, struct pixel *theArray );
void print(struct pixel a[]);
void my_Mirror(struct pixel a[]);
void rotate(struct pixel a[]);
void my_Flip(struct pixel a[]);



#include "transform.h"


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // declarations here
    FILE *inFile;


    // open input file
    inFile = fopen(argv[2],"r");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File open error. Exiting program\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    // set g_width and g_height
    parseHeader(inFile);

    // malloc space for the array (example given in assignment write-up)
    struct pixel * pImage;
    if(NULL == (pImage = malloc(sizeof(struct pixel) * g_width * g_height)) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed for image size" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // parseImage function call here
    parseImage(inFile, image);

    fclose(inFile); // cleanup

    if( 2 > arvc )
    { // then not enough parameters given on command line
        printf( "format is: %s followed by a number in the range 1..3\n",
                 argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, valid command line input

        // manipulate the image according to command-line parameter
        //              1: mirror image
        //              2: upside down image
        //              3: rotate to the right 90 degrees

    switch(atoi(argv[1]) )
    {
        case 1:
            my_Mirror(pImage);
            break;

        case 2:
            my_Flip(pImage);
            break;

        case 3:
            rotate(pImage);
            break;

        default:
            printf( "invalid command line parameter\n");
            printf( "parameter must be in range 1..3 inclusive\n");
            printf( "exiting\n" );
            free( pImage ); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;
    } // end switch

    print(image);

    free( pImage ); // cleanup
    return 0;
} // end function: main


void my_Mirror(struct pixel a[])
{
    int col,row;
    struct pixel temp;

    // note: following works irregardless if even or odd number of columns
    for(row = 0; row < g_height; ++row) //step through rows
    {
        for( col = 0; col < (g_width/2); col++) // step through first half of columns
        {
            // perform swap
            memcpy( temp, a[(row * g_width) + col], sizeof(struct pixel) );
            memcpy( a[(row * g_width) + col], a[((row+1)*g_width) - (1 + row)], sizeof(struct pixel) );
            memcpy( a[((row+1)*g_width) - (1 + col)], temp, sizeof(struct pixel) );
        } // end for
    } // end for
} // end function: my_Mirror
```

Comment: You can actually copy the pixel structs with regular assignments rather than `memcpy()`.

Comment: @Jongware, I provided my horizontal flip function as well, which works up until the call for the mirror function, because it functions similarly. I hope it helps further investigate this, because I am at a complete loss

Comment: Update guys, me being stupid, I actually didn't realize that the mirror function works as called in the flip function. So there must be something wrong in the way i'm calling it in my main